# upscale png pixel art without interpolation

Tags: ruby, squib

I would like to use some pixel art in my cards, and this comes in png format at a native resolution of 64x64 pixels. I need to upscale the images, say to 512x512 pixels, for printing, but I don't want them to be interpolated (I would like to keep the pixelated look).

How can I do this? Can I control the resampling algorithm used by squib, or I need to resize the image with rmagick? Since I'd like to distribute the scripts, I would like to find the most user-friendly way of doing this.

Examples:
[Upscaled, not interpolated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbJUt.png)
[Upscaled AND interpolated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeviP.png)

EDIT: clarification

Comment: It *will* be resampled, but you can always pick "nearest neighbour" to avoid blurring.

Comment: If you're printing, 64x64 upscaled to something else is only going to make a mess of things. Just place it in all its chunky glory. If for some reason you do need an image with higher resolution, be sure to scale to an integer multiple of the original. 500 is 7.8125x the original, so the grid will get messed up a bit by this resolution. Consider 512 (8x) instead.

Comment: Where can I control "interpolation" VS "nearest neighbour"? You mean through rmagick?
I'm happy to have it look pixelated, I actually want that. But I also need to have it at a resolution that makes it easy to print at a specific size. That's why I thought of scaling images up, without interpolation, and save the output to a A4 page PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [#sample](https://rmagick.github.io/image3.html#sample) method.

> Scales an image to the desired dimensions with pixel sampling. Unlike
> other scaling methods, this method does not introduce any additional
> color into the scaled image.